# C++ string size changing during loop

Tags: c++, string, loops, stack

My Program is suppose to read a string and then insert each character into the stack. I noticed when I print the `length`, which is the size of the word, it changes to some high number. For example: `word = "hello"` length will = `5` at first but eventually change to = `111`. Also When I use 2 letters I always get a segmentation fault. What is causing this? Why is the length of the word changing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Stack.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Stack stack;
    string word;

    cout << "Enter word: ";
    getline(cin, word);
    cout << word << "|"  << endl;
    int length = word.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        cout << "i: " << i << "\tlength: " << length << endl;
        stack.push(word[i]);
        cout << "TOP: "  << stack.top() << endl;
    }   



    while (!stack.isEmpty())
    {
        cout << stack.pop();
    }
    cout << endl;   
    return 0;
}


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define STACK_CAPACITY 1000
using namespace std;
class Stack
{
    private:
        int topIndex;
        char arr[];

    public:
        // Constructor
        Stack()
        {
            arr[STACK_CAPACITY];
            topIndex = -1;
        }

        // adds elements to "top" of array
        void push(char c)
        {
            // if stack is full, do not add
            if (isFull())
            {
                cout << "Push on full Stack" << endl;
                // terminate function
            }
            topIndex++;
            arr[topIndex] = c;
        }

        // Removes last inserted (push) element from the stack and returns it
        char pop()
        {
            // checks if Stack is empty
            if (isEmpty())
            {
                cout << "Pop on empty Stack" << endl;
                return '@';
            }

            // if not empty, remove and return last element inserted
            char temp = arr[topIndex];
            arr[topIndex--] = ' ';
            return temp;
        }

        // Returns but does not remove last inserted (push) element
        char top() { return arr[topIndex]; }

        // Utilities 
        bool isEmpty() { return topIndex == -1; } 
        bool isFull() { return topIndex == STACK_CAPACITY - 1; }
        int size() { return topIndex + 1; }

        // Destructor
        ~Stack() 
        {

        }

}
```

Comment: Change your declaration from `char arr[]` to `char arr[STACK_CAPACITY]`

Comment: "arr[STACK_CAPACITY];" is meaningless statement, and does absolutely nothing. `arr` remains a 0-length array, and attempts to add characters to it results in undefined behavior, and memory corruption.

Comment: why do you hate the stl? just use std::stack<char>

Comment: Its for school. I cannot do it with STL

Answer (score 4):

There are various problems in your `Stack` class that cause it to exhibit undefined behaviour.

For example, in the constructor

```
    Stack()
    {
        arr[STACK_CAPACITY];
        topIndex = -1;
    }
```

does not (as, I guess, you are expecting) resize `arr` to have `STACK_CAPACITY` elements.   It attempts to evaluate the value of            `arr[STACK_CAPACITY]` which, since `arr` is declared as `char arr[]`, does not exist.   Hence that statement has undefined behaviour.

Similarly, the `push()` member function

```
    // adds elements to "top" of array
    void push(char c)
    {
        // if stack is full, do not add
        if (isFull())
        {
            cout << "Push on full Stack" << endl;
            // terminate function
        }
        topIndex++;
        arr[topIndex] = c;
    }
```

attempts (on  the first call) to modify `arr[0]` - which also does not exist.

When behaviour is undefined - as it is in the above - anything can happen.   Including appearing to overwrite unrelated data or (in your case) overwriting parts of the string `word` in `main()`.

You need to read up better on the basics of C++, rather than guessing about how things work.   You have guessed VERY incorrectly.

Comment: This did not work at all. it resulted in an even worse segmentation fault and created multiple weird files called core.####

Comment: What didn't work? I tested your code with correct declaration and it worked fine. Also add boundary check, for example, change `arr[topIndex] = c` to `if (topIndex >=0 && topIndex < STACK_CAPACITY) arr[topIndex] = c;`

Comment: I only described the problem, Chrismar.   And the only solution I described is to read up better on the basics of C++, so you can write code that does what you expect rather than something else.   If that didn't work, it means you didn't follow the advice i.e. you're still guessing, and not thinking at all about what you are doing.    The code in my answer is a direct quote of YOURS - I have not changed it.   So, if you copy/pasted the code from my answer, you still have the same code you started with.